# parse andstringify a json object jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I have a tag wich contains a data object like this:

```
<a class="export-json" data-button="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]">Export json</a>
```

Those values are passed on data-button like this:

```
$(".export-json").attr("data-button", data);
```

`data` is a list which contains `json`.

data is like this:

```
[{
name: "John",
position: "663",
a: 15,
b: 48
},
{
name: "311",
position: "663",
a: 12,
b: 48
}]
```

So I want to convert that data object and download it as a JSON file.

```
$(".export-json").click(function(){
        var data = $.parseJSON($(this).attr('data-button'));
        exportJson(this, data);
    });

function exportJson(element, data)  {
    var results = "text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data));
    element.setAttribute("href", "data:"+results);
    element.setAttribute("download", "data.json");
}
```

If I do like this because of this `parseJSON` here `$.parseJSON($(this).attr('data-button'))` I get :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

If I remove the `parseJSON`, when I download the file I have this:

```
"[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"
```

I don't know why this is happening?

If I go through data everything is printed corectly:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
   var item = data[i];
   console.log(item);
}
```

can somebody help me please

Comment: How was `data-button` populated in the first place?

Comment: `[object Object]` is not JSON. It's the result of a call to `toString()` on random objects, but it obviously cannot be converted back to an actual object. How do you actually end up with that value in that attribute, and what are you actually trying to do with that?

Comment: You need to parse the `JS object` when the anchor tag is originally generated, otherwise, object data is displayed as `[object Object]`

Comment: That string is not JSON so you can't use a json parser on it. Need to back up to how you got that value in the first place. This is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Hydrothermal I edited the question, I added some other details

Comment: @You I tried to do the $.parseJSON before I add data on data-button attribute  but I had the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery `data()` method instead of `attr()`

Change:

```
$(".export-json").attr("data-button", data)
```

To:

```
$(".export-json").data("button", data)
```

Then it will be stored as array and won't require any parsing

If you really needed this in an attribute you would need to first stringify the array before assigning as attribute value